# CMake with flex/bison in CLion

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to translate a Makefile into CMakeLists.txt.

Makefile which works

```
fb1-5:  fb1-5.l fb1-5.y
    bison -d fb1-5.y
    flex fb1-5.l
    cc -o $@ fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl
```

CMakeLists.txt attempt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(calc)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

FIND_PACKAGE(BISON REQUIRED)
SET(BisonOutput ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/parser.c)
IF(BISON_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
            OUTPUT ${BisonOutput}
            COMMAND ${BISON_EXECUTABLE}
            -d
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fb1-5.y
            COMMENT "Generating parser.c"
    )
ENDIF()

FIND_PACKAGE(FLEX REQUIRED)
SET(FlexOutput ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/scanner.c)
IF(FLEX_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
            OUTPUT ${FlexOutput}
            COMMAND ${FLEX_EXECUTABLE}
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fb1-5.l
            COMMENT "Generating fb1-5.l"
    )
ENDIF()

ADD_LIBRARY(calc ${BisonOutput} ${FlexOutput})
```

It says it finds bison and flex in [[image]clion](/questions/tagged/clion)

```
-- Found BISON: /usr/bin/bison (found version "3.0.4") 
-- Found FLEX: /usr/bin/flex (found version "2.6.0")
```

But my CMake script won't generate an executable. How should I define "executable" and how can I make the CMake build script work in CLion?

Comment: `But how should I define "executable"` - what is wrong with `add_executable(fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c)`?  `how can I make the CMake build script work in CLion?` - What is the problem with current script? Documentation for [FindFLEX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindFLEX.html) has a nice example of using functions provided by this module (and by [FindBISON](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindBISON.html) module too). Have you checked this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But my CMake script won't generate an executable. How should I define "executable" and how can I make the CMake build script work in CLion?

I think you should at least do something like this:

```
add_executable(fb1-5
  ${BisonOutput}
  ${FlexOutput}
)
```

See [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html).